# java: Two Possible int Values: Score Tracker for a Game

Tags: java

I'm working on a project to create a Space Invaders style game:

- I need to be able to keep score when a player hits the target (+1 point) or misses (-1 point).
- I will call the recordScore() method when the player shoots at the alien entity, however, I am unsure how to set it up so that my value (int point) can either be 1 or -1.

This is what I currently have:

```
public void recordScore(int point){ 
if(/*an alien ship is hit*/){
    point = 1;
}
else{
    point = -1;
}
```

I will call the method as such:

```
    //if there is a hit    
    recordScore(1)
    //if there is no hit
    recordScore(-1)
```

...which I feel is a hint but I feel like using the loop is incorrect as I feel that would not work with how the method will be called but I can't currently think of any other way to initialize the variable to two values (or fill the if clause).

Comment: Can we see your class? I assume you're keeping track of the score on a class field somewhere right?

Comment: And what loop are you talking about? There are none in any of the code you posted.

Comment: I accidentally called the if-else statement a loop! So, the if-else statement!

Comment: Re: the class: I'm keeping score in a database using mySQL. However, I do have an int data type currentScore that is actually to be added to (+1 or -1) so perhaps that's what I should be looking into

Answer (score 3):

This is thinking backwards:

```
public void recordScore(int point){ 
if(/*an alien ship is hit*/){
    point = 1;
}
else{
    point = -1;
}
```

You are trying to assign a value to a method parameter which is the exact opposite of what you should be doing. Remember that point is coming into this method with a value assigned and passed into it.

Instead use the value that the parameter holds to assign to the value of a class field, or in your case to increment or decrement the value of a field.

So something like:

```
public void recordScore(int point) {
    score += point; // similar to score = score + point;
}
```

is closer to what you need. I have no idea if you have a score field and you may name it something else.

---

Note that you state:

> I feel like using the loop is incorrect

If you're referring to to the if/else structure, please understand that this is not a loop but rather a program control flow statement or logic block. A **loop** would make code repeat itself, and examples include for loops and while loops.

If you will only want to increment or decrement score by 1, another option is to use a method that uses a boolean parameter. For example

```
public void attemptHit(boolean hitSuccessful) {
    if (hitSuccessful) {
        score++;
    else {
        score--;
    }
}
```

and you'd call it like:

```
attemptHit(true); // for a successful hit
attemptHit(false); // for a miss
```

This will prevent nonsense but valid code from being created such as

```
recordScore(-23020);
```